# parsing xml in visual c++

Tags: xml, parsing, visual-c++

I want to  get the node values of the xml string in a visual c++ code

My vc++ code is something like this

url= _T("http://www.xyz.com/val");
CString result = g_pCAddonHandler->SendWebRequest(url, L"GET", L"", false);
// I send a request to a web url it returns an xml string and the format of xml is below

response

result name="response" numFound="1" start="0"

doc

str name="id">497888/str

str name="lastName" Ross /str

str name="name" Holly /str

/doc

/result

/response

Note:- I have not used < & > because stackoverflow doesn't allow these.

Please help in getting all the nodes.
I am relatively new in VC++.

Regards
Anil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
MSXML2::IXMLDOMDocumentPtr pXMLDom;
IXMLDOMNodeListPtr itemNodes = NULL;
CComBSTR bstrResp(szResponse);
::CoCreateInstance(MSXML2::CLSID_DOMDocument, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
        MSXML2::IID_IXMLDOMDocument, (void**)&pXMLDom);
BOOL bRet = pXMLDom->loadXML((BSTR) bstrResp);


if(bRet)
{
 itemNodes = pXMLDom->selectNodes(_T( "/response/result/doc/str[@name='id']"));
 CString szId =  itemNodes->item[0]->text
 ....

}
```

for details check this

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms756987%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Can you please elaborate it more. Give me a code which I can simply copy and paste...

Answer (score 2):

You can write your own XML Parser by tokenizing the string and getting all the nodes or use some already existing parsers like [TinyXML](http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxml2/index.html), Read [this](http://www.bluedinosaurs.com/code/blog/wordpress/2012/01/tutorial-using-tinyxml-part-1/) tutorial.

Comment: Can you please give an example how to parse the xml by tokenizing the string and getting all the nodes.

Answer (score 0):

If you find TinyXML difficult you could always try
http://pugixml.org/ .